# Why won't NodePorts in my Kind cluster work with this config?

Tags: kubernetes

Cluster configuration:

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 30081
    hostPort: 8234
containerdConfigPatches:
- |-
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."localhost:2500"]
    endpoint = ["http://kind-registry:5000"]
```

Deployment and service:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: debugtest
  labels:
    app: debugtest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debugtest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debugtest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: debugtest
        image: localhost:2500/debugtest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: debugtest
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: debugtest
  ports:
    - name: http
      targetPort: 5000
      port: 5000
      nodePort: 30081
```

Verified that docker is forwarding the port.

```
kindest/node:v1.25.3   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   127.0.0.1:39581->6443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8234->30081/tcp   kind-control-plane
```

Kind v0.17.0

Ubuntu 22.04

I can port forward the service via kubectl and reach the application in the debugtest pod.  Was expecting to be able to hit the application at localhost:8234 without a manual port forward but am unable to.

I also tried without the `extraPortMappings` per [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/99#issuecomment-721966227) but it still doesn't want to connect.  What am I missing?